add list of dictionary to existing pyspark dataframe as new column in python
i have a list of dictionarys in python that i want to add as new column in pyspark dataframe such as all any single item in the list will tranclete to a cell in the new column.
when i try for example to transform it to pandas add the column and transform it to py spark the data becoume corrupted and i can figure out the correct functions combo to add the data without using pandas i tried using lit but or add a structType to no success
thanks for the help.
here is an exmple to the data
my_list = [{"example1": {"subkey_example1": {"ex1": "2", "ex2": "4"}, 
            "example2": {"subkey_example2": {"ex3": "1", "ex4": "3"}}},
           {"example3": {"subkey_example3": {"ex5": "4", "ex6": "2"}, 
            "example4": {"subkey_example4": {"ex7": "1", "ex8": "3"}}}

here is example to the table
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
| data1 | data1 |
| data2 | data2 |
+-------+-------+

and the desire colume will be:
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
|column1|column2|            column3             |
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
| data1 | data1 | {"example1":                   |
|       |       |   {"subkey_example1":          |
|       |       |    {"ex1": "2", "ex2": "4"},   | 
|       |       |   "example2":                  |
|       |       |    {"subkey_example2":         |
|       |       |     {"ex3": "1", "ex4": "3"}}} |
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
| data2 | data2 | {"example3":                   |
|       |       |   {"subkey_example3":          |
|       |       |    {"ex5": "4", "ex6": "2"},   |
|       |       |    "example4":                 |
|       |       |    {"subkey_example4":         |
|       |       |     {"ex7": "1", "ex8": "3"}}} |
+-------+-------+--------------------------------+


To add the list of dictionaries as a new column in a PySpark DataFrame, you can use the pyspark.sql.functions.struct() function to create a new column with the desired structure.
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2)
], ["column1", "column2"])

# Define the list of dictionaries
my_list = [
    {"example1": {"subkey_example1": {"ex1": "2", "ex2": "4"}, "example2": {"subkey_example2": {"ex3": "1", "ex4": "3"}}},
     "example3": {"subkey_example3": {"ex5": "4", "ex6": "2"}, "example4": {"subkey_example4": {"ex7": "1", "ex8": "3"}}}
]

# Create a new column with the list of dictionaries
df = df.withColumn("column3", struct([col(f"value.{key}") for key in my_list[0].keys()]))

# Show the resulting DataFrame
df.show(truncate=False)

